# Is C# Session save / not manipulatable? Keep a user verified and logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I'm building a website for myself, connected to a user database.
As soon as the user logs in, i save the username into a session variable.
e.g. Session["User"] = anyString;
So everytime a user visits a page on my website, i check if this User Variable isnt null and matches a user in my database. If this returns false, i redirect the user to my home site.

now my question is, is this a safe practice?
Can the Session be manipulated / accessed from outside?

Comment: I think that this is a sound approach in principal. The session cannot be directly accessed from the client side.

Comment: I would also take a look at FormsAuthentication to allow ASP.NET to 'marshall' what pages can be accessed when not logged in etc.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t6b43z4(v=vs.140).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Session can Hijack in the ASP.Net

More Information :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/859579/Hack-proof-your-asp-net-applications-from-Session

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/suthish_nair/how-to-avoid-session-hijacking-in-web-applications/

For the prevention of Session hijacking , use proper security like form authentication, encryption etc.

Answer (score 0):

Session variable is in web server memory. So it cannot be manipulated outside server. Cookies and viewstate are accessible by client browser

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(v=vs.140).aspx